# Does Paladin's "Turn the Faithless" class ability affect his "Find Steed" mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin

One of the paladin's signature spells is Find Steed, which creates an intelligent mount which is either fey, fiend, or celestial. Would the "Turn the Faithless" (targets all fey/fiends within 30ft) class feature cause his own steed to attempt to flee?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Only if it's not celestial.

The rules on Find Steed and Turn the faithless are clear, you don't get to choose which fey or fiends are turned when you Channel Divinity, but you *can* choose to summon a celestial as the mount, so do that in order to avoid friendly-turning.